# EKS Terraform scale using cpu

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

Using terraform to instantiate an eks. How to configure when to scale the nodes? I would like to customize if the cpu reaches 40% for example.

My module eks:

```
module "eks" {
  ......

  worker_groups = [
    {
      name                           = "worker-group-1"
      instance_type                  = "t3a.medium"
      root_volume_size               = "20"
      asg_desired_capacity           = 1
      asg_max_size                   = 1
      asg_recreate_on_change         = true
      kubelet_extra_args             = "--node-labels=node.kubernetes.io/lifecycle=normal,instance_type=normal"
      tags = [.....
      ]
    }
  ]

  worker_groups_launch_template = [
    {
      name                    = "spot-family-t-low"
      override_instance_types = ["t3a.medium", "t2.medium","t3.medium"]
      spot_instance_pools     = 3
      root_volume_size        = "8"
      asg_recreate_on_change  = true
      autoscaling_enabled     = true
      asg_max_size            = 2
      asg_desired_capacity    = 1
      kubelet_extra_args      = "--node-labels=node.kubernetes.io/lifecycle=spot,type=t-low"
      public_ip               = false
    },
  ]
  workers_additional_policies = [aws_iam_policy.worker_policy.id]

}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html

Comment: Your node scaling is not directly based on usage. It's based on what's requested by pods. Pods themselves is what you scale based on usage.

Comment: @jordanm tks! The link gave me a guide, some tags were missing

Key Value
k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/<cluster-name> 
owned

k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled TRUE